# how to compile .cpp file for ros without main function?

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have created a .cpp file for ros. where i have to put the file and how can i compile it. this file is a standalone file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10728/how-to-compile-.cpp-file-for-ros-without-main-function??/) by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2011-07-26

Post score: -3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-26**:
What I know is when you create a package then you can use rosmake to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[1.3 Building your nodes](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#) 
You need to edit you CMakeLists.txt

To build a library take a look [at 1.2 Building a library](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists/Examples)

---

Originally posted by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) with karma: 482 on 2011-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for your answer. I got how to compile the single .cpp file without even having no main function.

you have to add two lines to CMakeLists.txt

rosbuild_add_library(gazebo_ros_xx src/gazebo_ros_xx.cpp),

rosbuild_link_boost(gazebo_ros_xx thread)

and then just type the command 'make'.

Hope this will be beneficial to others as well

---

Originally posted by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) with karma: 94 on 2011-07-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1